# WiFi auto discovery works in Window 10 but does not in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, drivers, atheros

I have successfully installed ubuntu 14.4 LTS alongside with Window 10 in my new Aspire E15 E5-573G-779S. WiFi auto detection in Window 10 is ok but not in Ubuntu 14.04. Appreciate if anyone can help to advise. Thanks. 
Results of lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 shows

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1299] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thx for the infor. But I can't try it out as my dual boot now fail to boot into ubuntu. I have to get back my dual boot first.

Comment: OK. Now my dual boot (window10 n ubuntu 15.10) is back and running. Yes I went through the above link of possible duplicate but I can't figure out what should do next. Pls help to shed some light.

Comment: What I meant was the changes done in the possible duplicate looks "intimidating". For Ubuntu 15.10, perhaps there is better solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you connect to any Wi-Fi manually in your Ubuntu system?

---

If your machine is a laptop, you need to make sure the Wi-Fi adapter (or "wireless network") is toggled ON when using Ubuntu. On most laptops there is a hardware toggle that controls this. You may want to check your BIOS settings, too, because there might be a software toggle there.

Usually you can enter your BIOS settings by pressing and holding key `F2`, `F10`, or `Delete` during startup when the some logo appears (this is usually referred to as the POST screen), before any operating system loads.

I found a manual for your computer, it is https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1027476497.pdf It says you can enter BIOS settings using `F2`.

In your BIOS settings there might be an option that turns on your Wi-Fi adapter at startup.

Comment: Thx for the detail. Pls pardon me if I ask a obvious clarification before I try it out. Your bios setting, is it in Window 10 or ubuntu environment? The wifi auto detection in window 10 has no problem originally, isn't that shows that bios setting is on already?

Comment: @CaseyYeow No. BIOS is independent from any OS. The thing is different OS might be play with the software toggles in different ways, which may lead to the issue you described. However, I am still not very clear what "Wi-Fi auto detection" is. Are you talking about "Wi-Fi auto connection" or "Wi-Fi discovery"? Can you connect to Wi-Fi in Ubuntu?

Comment: @CaseyYeow If you cannot even connect to Wi-Fi, it might be something wrong with your driver as is suggested in a comment to your question.

Comment: Yes  WiFi discovery . It is working in window 10 but not in Ubuntu, as the title of this thread meant.

Comment: In window 10 , WiFi can be discovered and connected, but not in Ubuntu , cannot be discovered or detected.

Comment: @CaseyYeow Okay. Can you also post your `lsusb` results in your question, other than `lspci`? For the Qualcomm adapter - is it an Ethernet adapter or a Wi-Fi adapter - or in other words, do you have an Ethernet port on your laptop?

Comment: @CaseyYeow To fix your dual boot, boot with a Ubuntu installation media, and run `update-grub`.

Comment: I am using the live USB media. To run update-grub, it must be in root. But in live USB, I used my password to enter root but it failed. So in live usb Ubuntu, how to run update-grub? Thx.

Comment: @CaseyYeow I can run `update-grub` directly in my live USB media. I think all commands are executed as root. If it asks for password when you use `sudo`, don't use `sudo` then...

Comment: Mine is different. It shows: grub-mkconfig: you must run this as root.

Comment: @CaseyYeow I have to admit I don't know why it is happening... I assume your installation/live media is the ISO image you downloaded from the official Ubuntu website right?

Comment: Yes, I tried http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd. However when comes to reinstall Grub2, it says" error: can't find EFI in the directory", so installing Grub2 failed. Why?? I checked my window 10 system information shows it is UEFI, secured boot disable, fast boot disabled. I don't know how to resolve, pls help.

Comment: Now my dual boot is working fine. I realised the changes done in the possible duplicate looks "intimidating". For Ubuntu 15.10, perhaps there is better solution for WiFi auto discovery?

Comment: @CaseyYeow  I don't understand what you would like to do. You want to try Ubuntu 15.10? I am not sure but if you don't have the correct driver for your wireless adapter probably you need to find one. 15.10 may have updated driver for you, or may not.

Comment: Solved. Just follow the answer by Jeremy in duplicate post above. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the Wi-Fi on ALWAYS ON in the BIOS. In my experience this will solve the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, sorry, how do you do that in Window 10? Thx.

Comment: You cannot do that in windows, it has to be done on startup of your computer. Like  explained by "bfrguci" you need to hold F2 on startup of your computer. So when you restart, hold F2 as soon as the screen goes black. Check his link for the user manual to see where you need to go in the bios menu.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my comment clearer. I am having dual-boot now, so which os to choose for starting up, to do this?

Comment: This is before you choose the OS. The BIOS (basic input output system) is a small system program built into the computer motherboard and is responsible for basic system settings and loading the os. So right the second your system starts up you need to press F2. So keep pressing F2 when you start up your computer.

Comment: I tried that just now n I can't find WiFi setting. So I exit n it asked me to save n exit. After I exit and reboot again, funny that my dual boot is gone!? Now it always go into window 10. Any idea why?

Comment: Very strange it now only boots into windows. Are you sure you didn't change the boot device (or boot order) by accident? Otherwise it sounds like the device is somewhat locked down and forces you to use only windows...

Comment: I checked I couldn't be change anything unless I pressed the F5 or F6, which I didn't touch at all. But, I think at last step I remembered I did "save changes and exit" which may disrupt the dual boot even though I did nothing. Anyone has similar experience?

Comment: I applied boot-repair via live usb-ubuntu but still failed to get back dual boot. I checked the boot order in bios, there is no Ubuntu there. Should I reinstall the Ubuntu via live usb-ubuntu? If so, must I format that particular partition?

Comment: You could try to reinstall Ubuntu. If you choose to do a full reinstall Ubuntu will format the drive for you. But if you like you could also format it yourself.

Comment: That particular partition was derived from shrinking C drive previously. In window 10 environment, I tried to right click that partition but the' format' option was not highlighted and thus cannot be chosen. May I know how do you do that? Also what do you meant by 'full reinstall'?  Thanks.

Comment: You can easily perform a full install using your live usb-ubuntu like you did before.

Comment: So I did a full reinstall  but the problem still persist. No dual boot menu displayed and checked the bios, no Ubuntu in boot order. Don't understand why??

Comment: Sounds very strange. My advice would be to find somebody in your neighborhood who can physically check out the problem. Maybe a friend or tech support of some sort. Maybe the guys at Acer can help you out with installing a second os.

Comment: I did this :sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda             931.5G            
├─sda1 vfat       100M            ESP
├─sda2             16M            
├─sda3 ntfs     430.1G            Acer
├─sda4 ntfs       448G            DATA
├─sda5 swap       3.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda6 ntfs       500M            Recovery
└─sda7 ext4      48.8G            
sdb               7.5G            
└─sdb1 vfat       7.5G /cdrom     UUI
sr0              1024M            
loop0  squashfs 962.1M /rofs      
Any idea what goes wrong and where is the grub? Thx.

Comment: sda7 is ext4 so it should be installed on that partition. During install of ubuntu you should install the bootloader on sda (not sda7). But be very careful because this will install the windows bootloader. In a system with a second hard drive you could choose that and choose the disk in the bios and with that the bootloader installed. In your case you only have a single disk with multiple partitions. The bootloader must be on the disk. WARNING: if you install and choose to install the bootloader on sda this will overwrite the windows boorloader!!! You should back it up!

Comment: Have a look at the following link on how to backup the bootloader (and also how to restore if needed), see: "Master Boot Record backup and replacement"

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Yes, I tried [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) However when comes to reinstall Grub2, it says" error: can't find EFI in the directory", so installing Grub2 failed. Why?? I checked my window 10 system information shows it is UEFI, secured boot disable, fast boot disabled. I don't know how to resolve, pls help.

Comment: for UEFI you need to create a GPT partition. You probably created an older MBR partition type (sometimes also labeled as msdos). During install you need to remove and then create the ubuntu partition choosing type GPT. So this is not about the file system type (EXT4, because this is fine) but about the partition type. but in order to change that it needs to be recreated.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition

Comment: Thx. I will choose - used as "EFI System Partition"  to create a GPT partition, right? For the new partition type , should I choose "primary" or "logical"?

Comment: Basically I will follow this http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/10/30/gpt-and-mbr-manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-15-10/ which shows for GPT, it has /efi , / , /home ,and swap.  All four have chosen new partition types as "primary" instead of "logical" , are they correct?

Comment: However, before I start recreate anything, I found out that in current "Disk Management" of Window 10, I saw there already exist the "EFI System Partition"!! Now I really don't understand why the dual-boot doesn't work. What should I do next?

Comment: Also I reconfirmed that my Disk 0 property is of type GPT, viewing via disk management in window 10.

Comment: I found and followed the first method in http://linux.about.com/od/LinuxNewbieDesktopGuide/tp/3-Ways-To-Fix-The-UEFI-Bootloader-When-Dual-Booting-Windows-And-Ubuntu.htm . Yes , when I reboot I can now see options for Ubuntu, advance Ubuntu and system setting. But I can't find option for Window! Pls advise how to have Window in the options???

Comment: I have solved it! just do "sudo update-grub"