# Full install to USB drive (not U.S.B installer)

Tags: usb, live-usb

Can you install Ubunta to a USB drive? So it is installed to a USB **as you would install it to a hard drive.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) and possible duplicate of [What's the best way to write an Ubuntu ISO image on a USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/whats-the-best-way-to-write-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-usb-stick)

Comment: i have several full installs on flash drives, both BIOS & UEFI. But I primarily use them for emergency boot on system with only one drive. USB2 is slow but functional if you change settings to reduce writes. USB3 flash drive is faster than USB2 flash drive even on USB2 port. Also better to use Lubuntu or Xubuntu as Unity just is larger and makes system slower. IF UEFI, you must gpt partition in advance. http://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition partitioning with gpt: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **you can**. You just have to point the Ubuntu installer to the USB drive manually during the installation by choosing "something else". (Keep in mind you can't install from a USB stick to itself)

**HOWEVER**, I would not recommend it. It will be slow to start up, and may perform excessive writes, eventually causing the USB drive to fail.

Rather, I suggest [creating a "live" USB stick with "persistence."](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: It would be nice if you added a link describing how to create a persistent USB stick.

Comment: @ByteCommander - Done.