# Ubuntu installer doesn't detect my USB drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install a copy of Ubuntu on a 32GB USB drive, and after having downloaded the ISO image and created the bootable drive with Rufus, I boot from the USB and start the installation process as normal. However, when I reach the option to choose which drive to install the OS on I am presented with my SSD (sda), HDD (sdb), and windows boot manager, but not the USB drive itself. Can anyone shed any light on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have similar problems if you partition the USB drive, put the installer on the first partition and have some space to put the OS on?

Answer (score 4):

That's to be expected. **If** you were allowed to do that, then the installer would overwrite itself, and then you'd get a kernel panic and/or an I/O error.

Besides, doing a full install to a USB drive [isn't a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/q/797392/518562) anyway.

Comment: Does a live session include the same features as a full install? For some reason I cannot change my screen resolution to the correct value, which I thought might have been a simple bug with the 'try before installing' version. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Ord3r - Yes, it includes everything. As for the resolution issue, did you try booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter?