# Install to a USB drive without another external drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, portable

I want to do a proper installation of Ubuntu to my USB drive so that I can effectively carry around my operating system everywhere I go (I say "proper installation" because I don't want to just use the "Try Ubuntu" option every time). It's 128gb so there's no problem there.

The issue is, every tutorial I've found seems to say that you need to first use the startup disk creator to write to a *different* external drive (e.g.  a CD), boot that, and then select the USB drive in the options. However, the only thing I have to write to is the USB drive itself.

I tried just proceeding anyway but it didn't seem to let me select the USB drive to install to (I'd have been amazed if it did).

Can I install Ubuntu to my USB drive without purchasing either a CD or another USB drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu installer doesn't detect my USB drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797404/ubuntu-installer-doesnt-detect-my-usb-drive)

Comment: Even if you did use a DVD to install to the USB, it isn't a good idea: http://askubuntu.com/a/797396/518562

Comment: P.S. I have a full install on an external HDD and take that with me wherever I go. Then you don't have the slow startup issue, and you have much more storage. Nor do you have to worry about excessive writes making the flash drive fail.