# How can I make a 14.04 bootable NON-FLASH USB drive

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd

I have a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 system. 
I have need of a bootable Ubuntu 14.04 external/USB NON-FLASH hard drive.

Most (all?) of the questions about making bootable external drives recommend USBInstaller and similar programs.  Some of these clearly assume a flash device, others are not always clear.

A CD-ROM is not an option as my laptop has no CD-ROM or DVD player, so my solution needs to be a standard, modern, USB actual hard drive.

Are there any software solutions that will accommodate this?  If not, how can it be done?

Comment: Is system UEFI? And do you want 14.04 in UEFI boot mode? If so be sure to back up the ESP - efi system partition on sda, as grub only installs to the ESP on sda. But you have to manually partition external drive, and use Something Else to install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot I also use grub2 to loopmount the ISO from my install on internal drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full install to USB drive (not U.S.B installer)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797392/full-install-to-usb-drive-not-u-s-b-installer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)