# Can't boot from clean install

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi, boot-repair

I've recently been having trouble booting my computer.

I tried to re-install some NVIDIA drivers after an update broke CUDA and led to some poor video performance. However that led to some conflicts, so I totally lost the graphics, and couldn't get beyond the command line TTY screen.

I tried a reboot, but it just hung after selecting Ubuntu 14.04. Then I tried the Boot Repair CD to no avail. [Here is the log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/20470855/).

As of now, trying to boot from it, I get `error: no such device: 90cc5126-fb61-4bb20aafe-b9ad22f26644`; then it goes into a boot rescue command line. I think something went pretty terribly wrong, because glancing at the log, it looks as though there's no OS detected at all.

After that didn't work, I unplugged all of my hard drives, hooked up a brand new one, and tried to install 16.04 on it, but again I couldn't boot. This time the error just said to insert a boot device. I again tried the Boot Repair CD, but it didn't work again. [Here is the second log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/20469479/).

I really appreciate any ideas that you'll have. I'm really not sure what it could be, but I'm a total novice with this aspect of any Linux system, so I thought it would be good to reach out to you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)**  Was your previous system an UEFI or a BIOS system?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! To be honest, I'm not sure; but if I were to guess I'd say EFI, because I did see an error before that said failed to mount efi. Although, since trying the boot repair cd, it hasn't gotten that far.

Comment: @wjandrea: if you do such a good job of editing mistakes, don't forget to also ass a few [enter]s to improve the readability of the Q!  *;-)*  (look at my edits)

Comment: Your first log shows no Ubuntu install on 2TB drive. Your second log shows an Ubuntu install on a 6TB drive that requires gpt partitioning. Is your system UEFI or older BIOS? If older BIOS may not work with that large of a drive. review these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Be sure to use 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have placed a brand new hard disk in an UEFI system, you first need to restore the UEFI partition. Try them in the following order:

1. The original System restore DVD/CD/USB from your hardware's manufacturer
2. The Open Source [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)
3. Go back to BIOS: no more worries about Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) problems.  This one is hardware-dependent and on some systems might need a BIOS-flash.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Fabby! Hopefully that does the trick!

Comment: @user1786476 Don't thank me!  Try it out and if it works, come back and click "✓"  **;-)**

Comment: Yep - turns out it resetting the mobo's CMOS settings was all I needed (for a fresh install to be able to boot). Thanks!

Comment: @user1786476 Favour returned: Q upvoted!  **;-)**