# Boot Partition Table Warning on clean 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I had windows and Linux dual boot on my computer. I now want to get rid of windows and do a clean install of Ubuntu, with a separate home partition. After setting my root, swap and home partitions as desired I get the following warning.

> "The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.
>
> If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition."

Here are my new partitions settings:

- free space            1      MB
- sda1   Ext4   ./      30720  MB
- sda2   swap           4096   MB
- sda3   Ext4   /home   465290 MB
- free space            1      MB

I would guess this warning is relevant if was to reinstall on a dual boot but can be discarded in my case.

Is this right?

gilles

Comment: You have gpt partitioning. Gpt requires either the ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot or the bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. How you boot install media is how it will install. It seems your Windows was UEFI as Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. Ubuntu can boot in either UEFI or BIOS, but if UEFI hardware probably better to use UEFI boot.  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition I always use gpt and add both the ESP & bios_grub all drives.

Comment: I'll ask two obvious questions. What made you decide to have separate root and home partitions, and why? Since you want a clean install, wouldn't it just be easier to put a clean GPT partition table on the disk and do a standard UEFI Ubuntu install?