# Ubuntu on plain new SSD

Tags: ssd

I just bought new 128GB SSD and I want to install ubuntu on it. Is it possible to instal ubuntu on plain disk with no OS ? I used rufus to put ISO picture to my flash drive.

Comment: There is no difference where to install Ubuntu to SSD or HDD.

Comment: Install will not be different, but are you installing in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. Instructions vary somewhat as boot is different. Also if only installing Ubuntu, you may want gpt whether UEFI or BIOS. But Windows is UEFI only on gpt partitioned drives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to instal ubuntu on plain disk with no OS ?

Of course. The 2 normal options are ...

- from dvd
- from usb

Basically set BIOS of the system to 1st try to boot from either option and not from the disk. It depends on the BIOS on how to do this but it either will have an option to set these or will have an option to create an UEFI partition where you can tell the BIOS to 1 time boot from a media you can pick. You then pick the dvd or usb.

Lots of system automatically default back to dvd or usb is there is no system installed yet on the disk. You could try this 1st too.

You do need another computer to download Ubuntu and burn it to an DVD or USB.

Comment: Thank you my ssd is comming tomorrow hope everything will run smoothly