# Additional partition of FAT32 created (size 512 MB) after installing ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo Laptop

Tags: fat32

[image]

Shall I delete the partition and add it to NTFS partition?

Comment: It looks like Windows is in the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt since Windows 8 released in 2012. But users could install in old BIOS/CSM/legacy mode on new computers with UEFI. But then installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode to MBR drive will not work with Windows in BIOS mode. If Windows is BIOS boot, you must convert Ubuntu to BIOS boot. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I don't even know the meaning of BIOS and UEFI till last month. I am a teacher by profession, not a software expert. Once I purchased my laptop back in 2012, they supplied it with a pirated win7 os. recently i installed linux os alongside my win10. previously i installed rhel and fedora, they were not that much speed enough. they hung all time. As my windows sitting in legacy mode, i could not wipe it again for uefi configuration. Will it make any problem if i change my lap to uefi completely?

Comment: UEFI has replaced BIOS, but has a BIOS mode for old systems. You cannot mix UEFI and BIOS on same drive if MBR (msdos) partitioned. Windows requires boot flag on its boot partition, but UEFI requires boot flag on ESP - efi system partition. You can only have one boot flag. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't delete it. Installing Ubuntu normally creates two partitions, one big one and then a small one. Most of Ubuntu is on the big one, but some of the instructions that the computer follows in order to be able to read the big one might be in the small one.

And now, for the longer explanation of what I think that partition is (trying to make it understandable, but I'm not sure what you and other readers know or don't know in advance, so I hope this is clear and isn't dumbing down )

I don't think the UEFI (the code that runs when you turn on the computer and figures out what should run next and reads that from a disk and runs it) knows how to read ext4 or NTFS, so some code is stored on a FAT32 partition, and that code contains the instructions on how to read the other partitions.

That is, I'm guessing it's the "EFI boot partition": [''EFI boot partition'' and ''biosgrub'' partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition)

I don't know how much of Ubuntu is stored on the small one. But at least some part of GRUB (the programme that shows a menu so you can choose when to boot Windows and when to boot Ubuntu) would have to be on a FAT partition.

In general, I wouldn't delete stuff without at least having some clue what it is and where it might have come from.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: Deleting this strange FAT partition lead to fatal error - you cannot boot windows nor linux. Repair of boot manager grub2 by reinstall linux create next 500 MB FAT partition - and you can do nothing with this. Another information - resize of disk partition in Linux lead to destroying partition for Windows.

Comment: Picture of partitions created by repairs of linux: https://i.imgur.com/EK79hXC.png