# ubuntu partitioning 500GB sata

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation

I going to install Ubuntu 18.04LTS on new hard disk, sata 500GB. Legacy BIOS, 4GB RAM.
Please advice partitioning schema,
swap
/ root
/home
usr
var
tmp

Comment: Use gpt partitioning and add bios_grub ( 1MB), so grub can correctly install to gpt drive. If drive may later be put in newer UEFI system include ESP as it also is not large (100 to 500MB). then only / & /home.  If standard desktop / only needs to be about 30GB and rest of drive can be /home or data partition(s). No real reason for separate system partitions. A few with servers may do that, still. https://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition

Comment: Boot mode is set to Legacy. Also, menu have UEFI options: UEFI OS, UEFI OS.

Comment: Do you have another OS on the system, or is it only Ubuntu.  If only Ubuntu then can change to UEFI with GPT partition before installing.  Do not change if there is another OS.

Comment: no other OS, clean disk. Why UEFI preferable?

Comment: Usually gives more choices and most recent OSs are setup for it.  As long as no other OS on computer(not disk only).  For partition/s you only really need /root, but can have /root and /home, 30 to 40GBs for root and as much of the rest for /home as you like, plus the small EFI partition.

Comment: A separate /home partition will use space that the / partition then will not have access to. Ubuntu will create it's own swapfile, swap partition not needed. If you ever need to copy your home directory to a new upgrade or install Grsync will make it easy enough.