# executing grub install dev nvme0n1 failed this is a fatal error uefi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I recently got a new laptop with 300 ssd hard drive. I dual booted the ssd with windows and ubuntu 20.4, everything seemed to work fine until I started getting this grub error `minimal bash-like line editing is supported` so I decided to format the hard drive into one partition and install only ubuntu 20.4 on the laptop.Now I can't install ubuntu again I keep getting this error `executing grub install dev nvme0n1 failed this is a fatal error uefi.`.

I've tried lots of things on the internet but now seems to work

It's probably also worth noting that I turned off secure boot and switched from UEFI to legacy because the ubuntu installation kept freezing at the purple loading screen on UEFI mode.

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 20.4 version might you mean 20.04?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292045) ?

Comment: Better to resolve error on UEFI install. Often you need graphic driver or Safe Boot during install & add proprietary drivers.  But if drive was UEFI, it then was gpt. And if then installing in Legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode, you have to have a bios_grub partition. If really wanting the now 40 year old BIOS type install, I might also have an ESP - efi system partiiton to make it easier to convert install to UEFI later.https://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition

Comment: Have you tried from the Bios menu, changing on the boot options, priority Ubuntu or different ssd options?
Also, is your usb ubuntu live written for both (UEFI and Legcy)?

Comment: i solved it by partioning the ssd maually during the ubuntu installation