# Install GRUB 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, 22.04

**I tried installing GRUB to 22.04 the same as with previous versions:**

> buntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sde
> Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: warning: this GPT
> partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be
> possible. grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can
> only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However,
> blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.. grub-install:
> error: will not proceed with blocklists.

I'm pretty sure there is a BIOS partition, it is a Full install USB.

[image]

Is this a new feature, Is there a work around?

Comment: i assume you know all this: https://askubuntu.com/a/500431/416663

Comment: Thanks @hiro protagonist. I do not seem to know all that as much as I think I did. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step Has worked well for me in the past, but is giving the error message when I try installing grub with 22,04.