grub set pager=1 failing
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 onto a machine and running into issues. The computer is currently booting into the grub> prompt.
While trying to resolve those issues though, it seems that somehow GRUB has become pretty broken.
At the top when it loads the prompt, and when you run many commands, it says to run set pager=1 to enable less(1)-like paging. However, running this gives:
grub> set pager=1
error: command failed.

Many other commands also fail with the same error, including the ones that I think I have to run to fix the loading of the kernel which is the issue. Since set pager=1 fails, I suspect this error has something to do with the GRUB prompt and fixing that will also enable me to load the kernel properly.
Does anyone have any idea how I could go about debugging what is causing a simple command like set pager=1 to fail with this error, and how to fix it?
Edit: Also worth mentioning that half the time it boots into this grub> prompt, but half the time it goes to the normal GRUB menu and can boot into Ubuntu successfully. When it goes to the grub> prompt all I can do is run exit to boot Windows.
There are two disks. There is a small one that contains the EFI system partition and the Windows C drive. And there is a large one that contains another NTFS partition, the Ubuntu root partition, and the Ubuntu swap partition. I assume GRUB is installed onto the EFI paritition on the small drive. Both drives are using GPT.

To start just run 'set' to show what existing environment variables are available and 'ls' to list your partitions to find the boot partition. (I think you are starting with very limited commands available.) Take a look at redswitches.com/blog/grub-rescue-commands to find your way around and attempt to boot directly from the grub prompt

@david set and ls do work. The issue is that the command I need to run to boot (insmod normal), and many other commands, fail with the same error. So I suspect the same error is caused by the same problem, which is something to do with grub and not the boot setup since set pager=1 is basic and should work. Also worth noting it is only sometimes loading into the grub> prompt. Sometimes it works fine. It's about 50/50 and seemingly totally random.

You should edit the question and add the 50/50 comment. As it sometimes works it suggests its a timing problem. Only the very bare bones of Grub is installed in the UEFI/GPT or MBR/BIOS  and the rest distributed in many places. (You should also add to the question which of these you are using.) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition for details. If your rig has two disks with the MBR/UEFI on one and the target Ubuntu partition on the other one may be starting slower than it should. I don't think it is a problem with Grub.

@david I've added more information. There are indeed two disks, one with the EFI partition and the other with the Ubuntu root partition. I'm not sure why that would cause something like set pager=1 to fail in the grub prompt, but if the timing of the loading is the main issue, do you know how I would go about fixing it? Thanks

Tricky. Off the top of my head and experimentally powerup into the BIOs which will give time for the disk drives to warm up. Don't change anything but just exit to normal boot. If this always boots correctly if adds evidence to the hypothesis. The obvious fix if you manage to accumulate enough evidence is to buy a new disk. You could try running 'Disks' and run the 'self tests' and see if it identifies anything for the alleged affected disk.  Best guess as to 'set pager=1' failure is it is trying to store this data on the the disk it failed to mount from cold.

@david Just tested by booting to the BIOS and then exiting, and it did not boot correctly. It went to the grub> prompt. Possible it's still an issue with the disks though, I imagine

I had faced this issue, it's all about BIOS problem so flash latest BIOS. Issue won't come again. Thanks
